# To find number of points inside a irregular shape

Tags: matlab, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

I need to find the number of points that I randomly generated inside a hexagonal boundary for two tier cellular network. The boundary is irregular shape.

I will show the sample of my code its not the full code:

```
final_y = [750 500 250 0 -250 -500 -750 -750 -1000 -1000 -1250 -1250  -1000 -1000 -750 -750 -500 -250 0 250 500 750 750 1000 1000 1250 1250 1000 1000 750 750]
 final_y1 = final_y'
XX =[1010;1155;1010;1155;1010;1155;1010;721.7;577.4;288.7;144.3;-144.3;-288.7;-577.4;-721.7;-1010;-1155;-1010;-1155;-1010;-1155;-1010;-721.7;-577.4;-288.7;-144.3;144.3;288.7;577.4;721.7;1010]

boundary = mx_min+(mx_max-mx_min)*rand(1,100);
boundary2 = my_min+(my_max-my_min)*rand(1,100);
figure(2)
plot(XX,final_y1)
hold on
%plot(boundary,boundary2,'or')
hold on
xv = [mx_max mx_min];
yv = [my_max my_min];
[in,on] = inpolygon(boundary,boundary2,xv,yv);
hold on
plot(boundary,boundary2,'bo',xv,yv,'ro');
```

I need to find the number of points inside that boundary.

Comment: What's your code? what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noted [`inpolygon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) function determines for each point if it is inside or outside a given polygon. All you have to do now is just count the number of `true` entries in the indicator vector:

```
[in,on] = inpolygon(boundary, boundary2, XX, final_y);
numPointsIn = sum( in );
numPointsOn = sum( on );
```

Comment: No its giving points in a square grid as I provided the limit as max value of X and Y and min value  of X and Y. Among the points distributed in the square I need to find the points inside that irregular structure.Boundary means inside that irregular shaped polygon.

Comment: @thomas how do you define your irregular boundary? can you specify `x`, `y` coordinates of its corners? Also, have you read the linked documentation of `inpolygon` there is an example there that does almost exactly what you need.

Comment: Yeah I'm defining the coordinates of that boundary.XX and final_y' is defining its coordinates, if you are plotting that coordinates you will get that boundary that I'm specifying.

Comment: @thomas in that case, you need to provide `inpolygon` with the boundary coordinates - please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information,what modification I need to add if I need to generate a fixed number of points inside that polygon ?